# Issue with removing negation terms (terms with a minus before them) from a ruby string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

The end user of our rails application can pass in a negative term in the url parameter. That's a term with a minus in front of it. An example is the following: `localhost:80/search?q=Arnold+Schwarz+-applesauce+-cantaloop`

I'm assuming in the params hash the value of `q` will be:

```
"Arnold Schwarz -applesauce -cantaloop"
```

I want to be able to populate an array in ruby that extracts all negative terms from the string. Here is my code below which does not seem to work correctly. It removes the -applesauce from the `query_string` and puts that into `ret_hash["excluded_terms"]`, but does not remove the `-cantaloop`.

```
query_string = "Arnold Schwarz -applesauce -cantaloop"
exclude_terms = Array.new 

def compose_valid_query_string(query_string)
    split_string = query_string.split
    ret_hash = {}
    split_string.each do |term|
        if(term.start_with?("-"))
            deleted_term = split_string.delete(term)
            ( ret_hash["excluded_terms"] ||= [] ) << deleted_term
        end
    end
    ret_hash["query_string"] = split_string
    return ret_hash
end
```

Comment: After `split_string.each do |term|` add the line `puts "split_string=#{split_string}, term=#{term}"` and all will be revealed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are deleting elements from the array while you are iterating through it. Exactly what happens in these cases is undefined, but it's common enough for it to cause the iteration to skip elements.

Another way to do this would be to use partition, which splits an enumerable into those elements for which a block is truthy and the remainder, for example.

```
negative, positive = split_string.partition {|term| term.start_with?('-')}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you works great. I'm saddened by the way ruby handles this though. I might as well use java iterator, since ruby does't even handle the obvious. At lease java throws an exception when modifying an iterable in place.

Comment: Horse, this behaviour is a characteristic of Ruby. There are many things that coders can do that might displease the Ruby monks, but coders tend to be given free reign. It can be argued that Ruby's elegance and power, as we know it today, is in large part a consequence of that policy.